# Can't connect to a NodeMCU ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I have a bunch of NodeMCU ESP8266 boards (bought three from here: https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07HF44GBT/), but for the life of me I can't figure out how to actually use them.

When I plug them in via usb (tried multiple ports, multiple cables), there's a small blue LED that flashes twice, then nothing else. Windows 10 doesn't make any noise suggesting I've plugged in a USB device. The list of USB controllers in Device Manager doesn't change.

I installed the CP210x Universal driver (https://www.silabs.com/developers/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers), but that didn't change anything.

I installed some more drivers from the github page (https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-devkit/tree/master/Drivers), but that didn't change anything.

I've tried this with all 3 of the boards that I received; no difference. The odds of all 3 being dead is quite unlikely, surely...

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: I’d suggest you check your USB cable.  The boards might not like being powered from a hub, so try direct to the PC (if you haven’t already).  It could be all three are dead - at that price point you’re not paying for premium hardware. So try a new cable, double check that it is plugged in fully and be gentle as the usb connectors on those boards can easily broken off.

Comment: Most of my el cheapo 8266s use the CH340 USB chip. Maybe check to see if you've got the correct driver installed. If it is a CH340 and it's still flaky, swap the USB cable. I've found the CH340 to be much more sensitive to differences in cables whereas the CP210x seems solid with any cable I use.

Comment: Yes, out of date esp8266/12x ch340/cp21xx adapters/drivers wasted me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that there's tons of micro-usb cables without data connectors. I bought some new ones that specifically said they support certain data transfer speeds, and I can now see the nodeMCU through a COM port. So... yeah, cables are very deceptive.